# Animate UILabel's width does not animate font size determined by minimumScaleFactor

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

When animating the `width` of a `UILabel` the font size does not animate according to the `minimumScaleFactor`.  Instead, when animating to a too small `width` for example, the font size jumps to the appropriate smaller size after the animation has finished.

Is there a way to animate the effect of the `minimumScaleFactor`?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setNeedsLayout` on the label inside the animation block?

Comment: @Losiowaty I did now: No difference. Why would that help? BTW, I did already call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the superview.

Comment: Try to implement this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097580/autolayout-animate-constraint-does-not-animate-subviews